# My custom font won't work

Tags: html, css

I've watched some videos and copied what they did but it's not working. I have my file in the same folder as my documents. Ugh, the site wants me to add more "details" or it won't let me post. I had my html and my css pages separated but it put them together. If you know how feel free to break them apart.

```css
.float-img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: none;
}

.potato {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-family: 'lazyspringday';
}

.p1 {
  font-family: 'lazyspringday';
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'lazyspringday', serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "lazyspringday";
  src: url('lazyspringday.ttf') format:('truetypefont');
}

.nav {
  background-color: #ffb6c1;
  color: #ffffff list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0
}

.banner {
  width: 100;
  display: block;
}

.banner>.bannerimage {
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav {
  margin: 0;
}

div.left {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 0 0 5%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left
}

div.right {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 0;
  float: right
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

.potato {
  color: #00b8e6;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'lazyspringday';
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="banner-image" src="ccc.png" width="100%" height="150px">

</div>

<ul class="nav">



  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="entertowin.php">Enter to Win</a></li>
  <li><a href="merchandise.php">Merchandise</a></li>
  <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
<img src="british-shorthair-3055340_1920.jpg" width: "400" height="400" class="float-img">


<p class="potato">
  Step into a magical world of cats at Cat Corner Cafe. Enjoy eating cute cat themed foods and drinks in a relaxing environment. Spend some quality time playing with some feline friends. Enjoy watching the cats have fun in an environment made just for them.
  All cats will be adoptable and provided by the local shelter. Cat Corner Cafe will also have fun events like cat yoga, art with cats and game days. Come by yourself, with your meetup group or have your next birthday party here! We look forward to seeing
  you. To be alerted when we open please sign up with your email on our homepage.
</p>
```

Comment: do you get an error? how do you know it doesnt work?

Comment: not sure if this is the problem, but I have always see @font-face being defined before being used. in your case font-face is not the first statement

Comment: I know it doesn't work because my font doesn't change. I tried putting it first right after body on my css page, it didn't help.

Comment: We could start with what browsers have you tried and what browsers it does not work on?

Answer (score 1):

first of all define @font face on the top and remove `":"` from format and rename **turetypefont** to **truetype**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "lazyspringday";
  src: url('lazyspringday.ttf') format('truetype');
  }
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

first and foremost, put your fonts in fonts folder seperately and css stylesheet in css folder, then include/import fonts in your css at top like this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lazyspringday';
    src: url('../fonts/lazyspringday.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lazyspringday.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/lazyspringday.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/lazyspringday.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/lazyspringday.ttf') format('truetype'),
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

we use woff and woff2 for using fonts in web.
you can also use web fonts generator to generate webfonts just uploading your .ttf file there.

Answer (score 0):

In the head tag of your html file (index?) place something like this:

```
<link href="(your file location)" rel="stylesheet">
```

After importing the font you can do it in several different ways. I'd recommend you to use a body tag that would contain everything on that html file.
If you chose to use the body tag, simply add this line to your css file:

```
body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

Use Google Fonts. https://fonts.google.com

Then copy this code into the `<head>` of your `HTML` document.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then use the following `CSS` rules to specify these families:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Comment: I want to use my custom font that I have a file of.